# Customizing the colors of a UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

Does anybody know of a way to customize the appearance of the string based UISegmentedControl? I am trying to set the background color of the cell and the text color differently depending on the selected state of the item.

Alternatively, do you know of a way to create UIImages on the fly in which to include custom strings? (e.g. create UUImage with white background, overlay text, add to segmented control).

I know that you can only have strings or images in the segmented control...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

UISegmentedControl has a tintColor property -- this allows you to change what color the control is, but not the general "style" (the rounded, beveled shape):

```
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

As for creating UIImages on the fly, you can create a CGContext, do whatever drawing you need to in that context (including strings), and then get a UIImage out of the context's CGImage:

```
CGContextRef drawContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(<many parameters>);
//do drawing here
CGImageRef finalImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(drawContext);
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage finalImage];
```

---

Please note, that if you use code like `UIView.appearance().tintColor = .myColor` (or equiv. in ObjC), the effect most likely won't take place.

Comment: Just FYI: Be careful if you're using something like `UIView.appearance().tintColor = .myColor` – I couldn't manually override the `UISegmentedControl`'s tintColor (neither storyboard nor code) so `UISegmentedControl.tintColor` got inherited from `UIView`'s tintColor. Thus I had to change that line.

Comment: @Muli Feel free to edit that information into my answer; the answer as is (a few days short of its tenth birthday!) predates the existence of `appearance()` by a few years.

Comment: It should be noted that as of iOS 13, tintColor is no longer a supported property of UISegmentedControl, even though it's not officially marked as deprecated. See Vinny's answer below for details, but you need to set selectedSegmentTintColor instead.

Answer (score 13):

```
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.61176f green:0.61176f  blue:0.61176f  alpha:1.0f];

segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

Answer (score 11):

Most of the answers here don't answer the specific question of how to set a button color based on selected state which implies another color is desired for unselected state.  I struggled with this for quite some time and wanted to share my solution for others to use.

My example uses a `UISegmentedControl` with three segments.  The unselected color for all three should be the same to give it a uniform look.  The selected state for the first and last segment have unique colors.

[image]

The issue is that the segmented control is not guaranteed to be in the same order so the colors will get mixed up as you select back and forth.  Dan posted a solution that uses tags but unfortunately it's no longer guaranteed to work for iOS 6 and up.

Most of this code is taken from [this post](http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/454). I changed it slightly to have unique selected colors.

What makes it work is the sorting but take note of these 2 important lines for setting the selected color:

```
NSInteger selectedIdx = betterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
[[sortedViews objectAtIndex:selectedIdx] setTintColor:[self.segmentColors objectAtIndex:selectedIdx]];
```

---

```
- (void) updateSegmentColors
{
    UIColor *checkColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 29/255.0 green:166/255.0 blue:47/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    NSArray *segmentColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:checkColor, [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor redColor], nil];

    UISegmentedControl *betterSegmentedControl = self.StatusControl;

    // Get number of segments
    NSUInteger numSegments = [betterSegmentedControl.subviews count];

    // Reset segment's color (non selected color)
    for( int i = 0; i < numSegments; i++ ) {
        // reset color
        [[betterSegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:nil];
        [[betterSegmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }

    // Sort segments from left to right
    NSArray *sortedViews = [betterSegmentedControl.subviews sortedArrayUsingFunction:compareViewsByOrigin context:NULL];

    // Change color of selected segment
    NSInteger selectedIdx = betterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [[sortedViews objectAtIndex:selectedIdx] setTintColor:[self.segmentColors objectAtIndex:selectedIdx]];

    // Remove all original segments from the control
    for (id view in betterSegmentedControl.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    // Append sorted and colored segments to the control
    for (id view in sortedViews) {
        [betterSegmentedControl addSubview:view];
    }
}


NSInteger static compareViewsByOrigin(id sp1, id sp2, void *context)
{
    // UISegmentedControl segments use UISegment objects (private API). But we can safely cast them to UIView objects.
    float v1 = ((UIView *)sp1).frame.origin.x;
    float v2 = ((UIView *)sp2).frame.origin.x;
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

---

I placed the code in it's own method because I'm loading these segmented controls in a table view and need to run it upon loading (existing states from storage) and when a user changes a selection.  Now I just need to call `[Self updateSegmentColors];` when something changes.

Answer (score 10):

All you have to do is:

```
// Get an array of the subviews of a UISegmentedControl, for example myUISegmentedControl:

NSArray *arri = [myUISegmentedControl subviews];

// Change the tintColor of each subview within the array:

[[arri objectAtIndex:0] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[[arri objectAtIndex:1] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly on iOS 7... you're amazing!

Comment: Good stuff nice solution

Comment: Inconsistent solution, order may change

Answer (score 7):

The best way I have found of doing something like this is setting different attributes for different UIControlStates on the segmented control.

```
self.segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor cb_Grey1Color];
self.segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor cb_Grey3Color];
NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIFont cbGothamBookFontWithSize:13.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                    [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [UIColor cb_Grey1Color], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[self.segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
NSDictionary *unselectedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [UIFont cbGothamBookFontWithSize:13.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                      [UIColor cb_Grey2Color], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                      [UIColor cb_Grey3Color], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[self.segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:unselectedAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: BackgroundColorAttribute just changes the background of the title

Answer (score 3):

Font Color swift 3 and swift 4 if you want to change

For Unselected item

```
 segcntrl.setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributes, for: .normal)
```

For Selected item

```
  segcntrl.setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributes, for: .selected)



//MARK:- Segment color change
    self.segc.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: 
UIColor.white], for: UIControlState.selected)
    self.segc.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: 
UIColor.white], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS13, you would be no longer able to modify the tint color of the segment controller.  Need to use `selectedSegmentTintColor` if the color has to be customized.

```
self.yourSegmentControl.selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor(red: 240.0/255.0, green: 183.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code that works with iOS9, but it is a hack, and might not work in later versions:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Title1", @"Title2"]];
for (id segment in [segmentedControl subviews])
{
    for (id view in [segment subviews])
    {
        NSString *desc = [view description];
        if ([desc containsString:@"UISegmentLabel"])
        {
            [segment setTintColor:([desc containsString:@"Title1"] ? [UIColor blueColor] : [UIColor greenColor])];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it via Interface Builder in XCode 6. Attached is the tint property:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to accomplish something similar - set the background color of the selected segment to one color while the 'outline' of the rest of the segments were a different color.

Borrowing heavily from [Portland Runner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709849/347339), the idea is to subclass the UISegmentedControl, and override 2 methods to both style the initial state as well as capture the change event to style it automatically as the user selects different segments.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self updateSegmentColors];
}
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self updateSegmentColors];
}
- (void)updateSegmentColors {
    NSArray* segments = [self.subviews sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
        // UISegmentedControl segments use UISegment objects (private API). But we can safely cast them to UIView objects.
        float v1 = ((UIView *)obj1).frame.origin.x;
        float v2 = ((UIView *)obj2).frame.origin.x;
        if (v1 < v2) return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (v1 > v2) return NSOrderedDescending;
        else return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
    for (int i=0; i<segments.count; i++) {
        if (i == self.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            [segments[i] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        } else {
            [segments[i] setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.0**

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
     // For selected segment
      control.selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.red
 }

 // For control's background 
 control.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Answer (score -1):

### Storyboard Solution

Xcode 11

Select the control and multiple color options are now available. If you need further refinement - check out User  Defined Runtime Attributes.

[image: image2]

[image: image1]