# UISegmentedControl app load color

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

In main storyboard prop and UISegmentedControl setting tint color selected to some color. But when app didi load UISegmentedControl switcher loading as default system color.
[image]

Wanted color more lighter. After couple clicks color comes as i want to:

[image]

When I'm setting color manually in viewDidLoad

```
self.genderSwitch.tintColor = [UIColor ...];
```

it loads it as i want with my wanted color. What the problem? Why it can't load it with my color without additional color setting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12454395/2792531 Does this solution work for you?

Comment: @nhgrif this is actually what i did. But it's kind of kludge: "lets set color in storyboards settings, and then, because something not working, lets assign color programmatically." It's huge dirty kludge.

Comment: If you got it working, you should post the solution as an answer and accept it.