# Is it possible to set different colors for segmented control?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I can't set different colors for a segmented control. I don't want to contrast colors. For example, index 0 will be black and white, index 1 will be pink and blue.

Has anyone tried that before?

Comment: Here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196679/customizing-the-colors-of-a-uisegmentedcontro] (Customizing the colors of a UISegmentedControl)

Comment: Use the `switch` or the `if-statement` and check the segmented control's state. For example: `if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.black } else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 { segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.green }`